# Background page loading in a frame in universal windows app

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app

I have a SplitView control in my UWP app and when a particular ListBoxItem in the SplitView pane is Tapped a frame in the Main Page should navigate to that page. I have written the following code for that

```
private void Page2_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PageLoadingProgress.IsActive = true;
        MainApplicationSplitView.IsPaneOpen = false;
        MainApplicationFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
        PageLoadingProgress.IsActive = false; 

    }
```

The issue I am facing is, whenever a ListBoxItem is tapped the whole app becomes unresponsive until Page2 is Loaded. The PageLoadingProgress ProgressRing cannot be seen and the SplitView pane doesn't close immediately as I expected. How to make this work? I want the pane to be closed and ProgressRing displayed when the page is loading and the app should be responsive.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the work on UI thread, it blocks the UI and causes the lag you experienced.

This link should help you http://wpdev.apps-1and1.net/dispatcher-yield-when-and-how-to-use-it-on-winrt/